# TCPListener Not Accepting Connection

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcplistener

I'm having an issue with a TCPListener.  I have created this code below and it works with a test application, but I can't get it to receive the connection from the production box.   In the image below  you can see .44 is continuously attempting to connect, but as seen in the Console window output, no connection is ever received beyond the Listening Started.

What am I overlooking?

```
    public class TCPServer
{
    #region Privates
    private ILog log;
    private readonly string _connectionString = "";
    private readonly List<AgentState> _lAgentState;
    private readonly DateTime _lastUpdatedRecord = new DateTime();
    private readonly TcpClient _tcpClient;
    private readonly IPEndPoint _serverEndPoint;
    private int _messageNumber = 2;
    private TcpListener _tcpListener;
    private Thread _listenThread;

    #endregion

    public IEXHermes()
    {
        var methodName = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;

        try
        {
            log = LogManager.GetLogger("Logger");
            log.Info("Class Starting");
            _connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.HN_ConnectionString;
            _lAgentState = getInitialState();
            _lastUpdatedRecord = _lAgentState.Max(w => w.actionLocalTime);



            Int32 iexPort = Int32.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.IEX_Port);
            _tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, iexPort);
            log.Debug("Server Open on Server: " + IPAddress.Any);
            log.Debug("Server Open on Port: " + iexPort);
            _listenThread = new Thread(listenForClients);
            _listenThread.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            log.FatalFormat("{0} - {1} \n {2}", methodName, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void listenForClients()
    {
        var methodName = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;
        log.Debug(methodName + " Starting");

        try
        {

            log.Debug(methodName + " - Listening Started");
            _tcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var client = _tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
                    var clientThread = new Thread(handleClientComm);
                    clientThread.Start(client);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.FatalFormat("{0} - {1} \n {2}", methodName, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.FatalFormat("{0} - {1} \n {2}", methodName, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace); 
        }
        log.Debug(methodName + ": Listener Closer");
    }

    private void handleClientComm(object client)
    {
        var methodName = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;
        var tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        log.Debug(methodName + ": New Connection Established");
        try
        {

            var clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            var message = new byte[4096];

            while (true)
            {
                var bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                var encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                var a = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved: " + a.ToUpper());

                if (a.ToUpper().Contains("INIT"))
                {    
                    a = sessionInitialize(); 
                } 
                    tcpClient.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a));

                Console.WriteLine("Sent: " + a);

            }


        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.FatalFormat("{0} - {1} \n {2}", methodName, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);   
        } 
        finally
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Wireshark Capture]

Comment: If you can connect locally, it's likely to be a network issue - do you have a firewall that could be blocking it?

Comment: I don't believe so, the Wireshark image shows the attempted connection from .44

Comment: Jason, I am assuming the wireshark image is on the client?  The production box may well have port 44 blocked, so it will show the attempt on the client, but the server will never know an attempt was made.

Comment: The screen shot above is from the server, the console screen with the green text is my server application.  Wireshark is also run on the server, showing connection attempts from .44, so I don't believe it to be a connection issue.

Comment: It is possible depending on your firewall, for your server to register a connect on a port. It sounds strange, but I have had this issue in the past many times, often setting up multiplayer games with TCP/IP. I had a few cases where it would say 'player has connected' on the server, but no data was transmitted and the connection failed soon after. It turned out to be a firewall in the router. A logical set of tests would be to telnet in to localhost on the server, have your program echo anything you send, and try telnetting again from another machine, just to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try to replace IPAddress.Any by the real IP at least for testing purpose, just to be sure...

Comment: Interesting point here, I tried that and am getting an error "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

Comment: So you're creating a socket (the TCPListener) on a port which is already in use. Either IEXHermes is called several times (this is not shown in your code) or you have another app using the same port.

Comment: This end up leading me to the answer, it was a mis-configured network card.