# I can't connect to test a local server started with TcpListener

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcplistener

Disclaimer: this is my first foray into anything directly tcp/socket related. I've read -[the](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f(v=vs.110).aspx)- -[following](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using)- -[resources](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ajyadav123/applied-C-Sharp-net-socket-programming/)- and am trying to come up with a very simple test application.

I'm trying to develop a local server running with a TcpListener object. I can instantiate it fine and run `netstat` to see the port in the LISTENING state. However, I can't telnet or create a test client to connect manually. Telnet says simply that it could not open a connection. Trying a test client application throws the exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447964/tcplistener-not-accepting-connection) SO question, the asker ultimately resolved it via a faulty NIC. How might I look for that?

This leaves me puzzled. How do I ever test or connect to the server? Here's my code.

For the server:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TcpConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var localPort = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["localPort"];
            var portNumber = int.Parse(localPort);

            var maxConnections = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["maxConnections"];
            var maxConnectionsNumber = int.Parse(maxConnections);

            Console.WriteLine("Preparing to start server on port {0}", portNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Max connections: {0}", maxConnectionsNumber);

            var ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portNumber);

            Console.WriteLine("Starting server with local IP {0}", ipAddress);

            var listener = new TcpListener(localEndPoint);
            listener.Start(maxConnectionsNumber);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Server started...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            
            while (true)
            {
                var socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    ProcessSocket(socket);
                });
            }
        }

        private static async void ProcessSocket(Socket socket)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = new NetworkStream(socket))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    writer.AutoFlush = true;

                    var received = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                    Console.WriteLine("Received: " + received);
                }

                socket.Close();
                socket.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error processing a message.");
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Seeing the above code running:

[image: TcpConsole running and getting to "Server started..."]
[image: Seeing the connection in the LISTENING state with netstat]

For the test application:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace TcpConsoleClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            var remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3245);

            var client = new TcpClient(remoteEndPoint);

            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.AutoFlush = true;

                string input;

                while((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(input);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TCP/IP connection has a local IP address and port, as well as a remote IP address and port.

Generally, a port number can only be assigned to one socket at a time. The error message indicates that an attempt was made to associate more than one socket with the same port number.

The reason why can be found in the client code:

```
var client = new TcpClient(remoteEndPoint);
```

This overload of the `TcpClient` constructor accepts an `IPEndPoint` specifying the *local* endpoint. That is, when the `TcpClient` is constructed, it will get bound to the port number specified by `remoteEndPoint`, which fails, because that port number is already in use by the server application.

To fix this, use the parameter-less `TcpClient` constructor, and instead pass `remoteEndPoint` to the `Connect` call:

```
var client = new TcpClient();

client.Connect(remoteEndPoint);
```